# Why when importing base64 in python my prints are done twice (x2)?

Tags: python, base64

```
import base64
image_base64 = 'Hello World\n'
print image_base64    
print 'Hello?\n'
```

Result:

```
Hello World    
Hello?    
Hello World    
Hello?
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all...

Comment: Wait, is your file named `base64.py` and you're somehow doing a recursive import?

Comment: @Suever: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file must be named `base64.py` so when you import `base64` at the top of the file, it is importing itself causing the `print` statements to execute twice (once on the import and once afterwards).

You should rename your script to something whose name does not conflict with the name of a standard module.